# Defining a listings style and available options

Tags: formatting, listings, documentation

When defining a style for a listings environment, I can set the background color by doing:

```
\lstdefinestyle{highlight}{
  backgroundcolor=\color{orange}
}
```

Apart from `backgroundcolor`, which other options are available? In particular, how can I set the *font weight* to *bold*?

Comment: There a lot options, all described in the documentation. The font can be changed e.g. with `basicstyle`.

Comment: add `,basicstyle=\bfseries\footnotesize` in your MWE.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 8):

> Apart from backgroundcolor, which other options are available?

Most packages have a documentation. The documentation is available on your computer. You can open the documentation with the command line:

```
texdoc <packagename>
```

The command `texdoc` has same extra options which are documented, too. Run:

```
texdoc texdoc
```

to open the documentation. Of course it is also available in the web.

[Online version of `texdoc`](http://tug.org/texdoc/)

Based on the given information you can open the documentation of `listings` by

```
texdoc listings
```

If you want the online documentation go to CTAN:

[`listings` at CTAN](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings)

In section *4.6 Figure out the appearance* you find the option `basicstyle` which is documented as:

> is selected at the beginning of each listing. You could use
>   `\footnotesize`, `\small`, `\itshape`, `\ttfamily`, or something like that.
>   The last token of basic style must not read any following characters.

The package `listings` provides an extra development documentation. For this

1. download the file [listings.zip](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings)
2. extract the file [listings.zip](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings)
3. run `make all`

The result will be the huge pdf-file `listings-devel.pdf`